# How to set Background image in UITableViewCell from interface builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I know that how I can set image for the cells in my static UITavleView programmatically:

```
cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
```

I could set the background color, but not the image.
Is it possible to set it from interface builder?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new user interface Xib file. Delete the initial view. Drag and drop your uitableviewcell into the builder. Customize...
Then put this in viewDidLoad:

```
 UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"pizzaCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib
      forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"pizzaCell"];
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath do this:

```
static NSString *cellIdent = @"pizzaCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent];
```

Now you have your nib cell. If you want to get references to the views you added to the cell the way I do it is to give em tags and call viewWithTag on the cell.

You might also just be seeking:

```
 cell.contentView.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PizzaImage"];
```

Not sure how much you want to customize

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by connecting the backgroundView outlet of the tableViewCell (with another view in the nib file). But you *cannot* make stretchable images within the interface builder..